# Cython+distutils build on Ubuntu Python 3 changes the module lib name during linking

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I'm using Cython and distutils.  *During* one of my tests, a binary extension module is built. After this, one of my other tests will `import` the binary module and test it. On Travis-CI, the linker command changes the name.  See in the screenshot below: the compiler correctly builds `test01.o`, but the linker incorrectly creates `test01.cpython-34m.so`: I want `test01.so`.

[image]

The above screenshot is for Python 3.4; the problem doesn't happen for Python 2.7, leading me to suspect that the Python-specific distutils may be doing something differently.

The distutils `setup()` function, which is called from my main script, does nothing special:

```
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Here `ext_modules` is a sequence of `Extension()` classes, imported from `distutils.extension`.

I have gone throught the distutils docs for 2.7 and 3.4 and nothing jumps out at me as different. What could be causing the name change, and what options could I specify, either in `setup()` or `Extension()` instantiation to prevent the name change?

---

**Edit:** I have set up a local VM running Ubuntu 13.10 and can confirm that, as described above, Python 2.7 produces `test01.so` while Python 3.4 produces `test01.cpython-34m.so`. Therefore this issue has nothing to do with travis-ci and I am removing that tag and editing the title.

---

**Edit:** Indeed it is a change to `distutils`, [made in 3.2](http://bugs.python.org/issue16754).  I'm still figuring out what I can do to get my import statement to look right.

---

**Edit:** OMG the helloworld example in the python docs produces `helloworld.cpython-34m.so` on Python 3.4.1 (Anaconda) on Ubuntu 13.10. Python's `sysconfig` module starts up with `sysconfig.get_config_var('SO') == 'cpython-34m.so'`.

I feel a rant coming on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mystery solved, thanks to @ncoghlan_dev.  The renaming change was made in [PEP 3149](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/). It turns out that even though the binary extension module might be called something like `helloworld.cpython-34m.so`, when you are actually in a python interpreter, `import helloworld` *still works*.  My travis tests were failing because I had a test that checked for the *name* of the compiled `.so` file. If I remove that test, the rest of the file should still work.